# SQL Server > copy certain rows and change 2 values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm selecting my data with the following statement:

```
select distinct min(revision_number) as revno,po_number 
from PO_HEADER 
group by PO_NUMBER
having MIN(revision_number) > 0;
```

I get the following data:

```
7   30492-SA-EH504
20  30492-PS-SO895
20  30492-RA-DD219
26  30492-SA-KK474
1   30492-BA-AT236
17  30492-RA-DD386
21  30492-PS-FS803
25  30492-PS-WM324
33  30492-SA-NS011
```

I want to copy the row with the `min(revno)` and set it's `revno` to ZERO. I've tried insert into using the entire table and using `where exists` and my `select` statement above and it copies the entire table.

This is what the table for `30492-SA-EH504` current looks like:

```
30492-SA-EH504 7
30492-SA-EH504 8
30492-SA-EH504 9
30492-SA-EH504 10
```

Here's how I would like it to look after:

```
30492-SA-EH504 0
30492-SA-EH504 7
30492-SA-EH504 8
30492-SA-EH504 9
30492-SA-EH504 10
```

I was browsing the MSDN for T-SQL to figure out how to use exists in this case, but as I said it either copies everything or nothing the way I am failing to do it currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into PO_HEADER(po_number, revision_number, ....other columns)
    select POH.po_number, 0, ...other columns
    from PO_Header AS POH
    INNER JOIN (select po_number, MIN(revision_number) as min_revision_number
        from PO_HEADER 
        group by PO_NUMBER
        having MIN(revision_number) > 0) AS POHMin ON POHMin.po_number = POH.po_number
            AND POHMin.min_revision_number = POH.revision_number
```

Comment: I should have been more detailed.  The table is ~ 147 different columns.  I was using the above as representative of the specific fields I was trying to change.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT RevNum = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY po_number ORDER BY revision_number)
         , revision_number
         , po_number
    FROM PO_HEADER t
) 
INSERT INTO PO_HEADER 
SELECT 0, t1.po_number
FROM CTE t1
WHERE t1.RevNum = 1
AND EXISTS(
    SELECT  NULL FROM CTE t2
    WHERE   t2.po_number = t1.po_number
    AND     t2.RevNum > 1
)
```